# Prevent mobile data from automatically turning off after a while on Xiaomi Mi 4

Tags: mobile-data, xiaomi-mi4

I use Xiaomi Mi 4 (Android 7.1.2 Nougat) phone's hotspot to surf the internet on a laptop. After sometime approximately 20 minutes, the phone automatically turns off the mobile data and I have to turn on the mobile data manually.

I think the phone turns off the data automatically because it is left undisturbed and to save battery. However, the phone is already plugged-in to the charging spot.

How to prevent mobile data from automatically turning off after a while on Xiaomi Mi 4?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have incorporated the info to the question while also removing unnecessary/unrelated info to solve the issue. If I accidentally removed/changed the meaning, feel free to [edit] and improve the question. Thanks.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3au0S.png

Comment: Thanks @alecxs the last option in developers options > always keep cellular data open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solved my problem

developer options > Networking > Cellular Data always active

toggle this option on